# l face the error SOURCE FILE Not COMPILED While running my C code in Dev-C++, any solutions?

Tags: c, ide

I try to run a simple code on Dev-C++ but it doesn't work.
It says "source file not complied."

[error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVt3b.jpg)

I've read suggested solutions on the net, some of them didn't seem relevant.
This website is suggesting restarting windows, but I don't want to reinstall all the applications I need.
https://wisegot.com/how-to-solve-source-file-not-compiled-in-dev-c/#gsc.tab=0
I tried installing the app in a different location, didn't work.

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between "restarting windows" and "reinstalling windows"? You seem to confuse those two terms.

Comment: @Yunnosch The nonsense article linked in the question does indeed speak about backing up all your files and resetting the PC.

Comment: @CherryDT Oh dear. I stopped reading that link after the first two lines of gibberish. Any online translator does a better job of turning a sensible text from any language into English.

Comment: Wildly guessing, which is why I do not create an answer, the most likely vaguely meaningful interpretation of that error message is "You tried to execute a source code file. You can however only execute the result of compiling/building it. I.e. please try to execute the resulting executable file; which on windoes e.g. usuall has the extension '.exe.'  instead of ' .c' ."

Comment: Wasn't this one of those IDEs that let you run from a source file without creating a project? If so you did perhaps not compile & save the file before hitting run. Please note that Dev C++ is severely outdated and you should look into getting a newer IDE with an up to date compiler.

Comment: If you tag it with IDE you might get a better audience.  It's not really a C question.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for your help. I've  already compiled it, I did it again to be sure, the error still happs.

Comment: Then maybe the IDE is struggling to find the generated object files and/or executable.